# Why does the deltatime in my android gameloop randomly gets very large?

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, surfaceview, game-loop

I want to start writing a simple 2d game for android and decided to draw everything on a cavas. But already my gameloop doesnt work well. Anyone has any idea why the deltatime in my gameloop (look below) randomly gets very large and causes a stuttering canvas?

```
@Override
    public void run(){
        while(running){
            if (!holder.getSurface().isValid()){
                continue;
            }
            float deltaTime;
            int sleepTime;

            Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (holder) {
                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                //update
                background.update();
                bomberman.update();

                //draw
                if (background.getX()+background.getiWidth() >= 0 || (background.getX() >= 0 && background.getX() <= getWidth()))
                    c.drawBitmap(background.getBackground(), background.getX(), 0, null);
                if (background.getX()+background.getiWidth()+background.getiWidth() >= 0 || (background.getX()+background.getiWidth() <= getWidth()))
                    c.drawBitmap(background.getBackground(), (background.getX()+background.getBackground().getWidth()), 0, null);
                c.drawBitmap(bomberman.getImage(), bomberman.getX()-(bomberman.getImage().getWidth()/2), bomberman.getY()-(bomberman.getImage().getHeight()/2), null);  

                deltaTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
                sleepTime = (int) (FRAME_PERIOD - deltaTime);

                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
                paint.setTextSize(40);
                c.drawText("deltaTime:" + deltaTime, 10, 50, paint);
                c.drawText("sleepTime:" + sleepTime, 10, 100, paint);
            }
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);

            //faster
            if(sleepTime > 0){
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            //slower
            while(sleepTime < 0){
                //update
                background.update();
                bomberman.update();
                sleepTime += FRAME_PERIOD;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The size of my background image is 125kB... is this too big?

Comment: Just a guess. `deltaTime` is a `float` while `System.currentTimeMillis() -  startTime` will return a long. I can not remember if Java needs casting but that would explain the random value for delta time. Try `deltaTime = (float)(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `System#currentTimeMillis()`.  On Android, That uses the device's "wall clock" as its time source.  If the network decides to update the clock, the current time will jump forward or backward.

Since you're only interested in the time delta between frames, use [`System#nanoTime()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) instead.  It uses a monotonic clock.

FWIW, you can improve your game loop by using [Choreographer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Choreographer.html) (API 16+) to get the actual display refresh times, rather than stuffing the display queue full.  See the [explanation here](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#loops).

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. Do you have an example where someone uses a Choreographer?

Comment: See the "record GL app" Activity in Grafika. It uses Choreographer, and drops frames as needed to maintain a consistent animation rate even when the system bogs down. https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/RecordFBOActivity.java  (Several of Grafika's activities use Choreographer, but this one included a dropped-frame counter so you can watch it work.)